# failed with Received heartbeat from member with the same member ID as ourself:0

Tags: mongodb

Trying to set a replica set configuration for 1 primary , 1 slave and 1 arbitrator. 
I have setup this in the `/etc/mongodb.conf`

```
replication:
  replSetName: ProductionReplicaSet
```

but accidentally ran `rs.initiate()`  on the three servers. now when I'm running `rs.add("mongo02....")` i'm getting :

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: chef-production2-mongo01:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: mongo02...:27017 failed with Received heartbeat from member with the same member ID as ourself: 0",
    "code" : 74
}
```

I read here that `rs.initiate()` can be reversed but the instructions are not clear.

tried on mongo02:

```
config = rs.config() //config with _id :0
config["members"][0]["_id"] = 1 
rs.reconfig(config)
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "New and old configurations both have members with host of chef-production2-mongo02:27017 but in the new configuration the _id field is 1 and in the old configuration it is 0 for replica set ProductionReplicaSet",
    "code" : 103
}
```

any help? i'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran in to this as well.   Turns out it can be caused by two things.

```
1.  If the node you are adding already has its own dbData.  

2.  If you ran rs.initiate() on both nodes.   It is only supposed to be run on the primary.
```

To resolve this you will need to check /etc/mongod.conf for the "dbPath" attribute and move or remove all the files in that folder.