# Error node not found when setup replica set in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm having extreme frustration trying to setup a MongoDB replica set from scratch.
I have 2 machine run debian os and installed mongodb. When i try use rs.add() to add member to replica set then i appear error although i still connect to mongodb by

```
mongo --host 13.212.31.212:27017
```

Here is the error messages

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("13.212.31.212:27017")
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1597144435, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 192.168.0.59:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 13.212.31.212:27017 failed with Received heartbeat from member with the same member ID as ourself: 0",
    "code" : 74,
    "codeName" : "NodeNotFound",
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1597144440, 1),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the mongod conf

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
journal:
enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
destination: file
logAppend: true
path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.26.2.229


# how the process runs
processManagement:
timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: According to this similar question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41969210/788223 this error could be because either rs.initiate() was ran on both nodes (you only need to run it on the primary) or the node you are adding already had data in its db path.

Comment: Why do you have two private IP ranges and one public IP range mentioned in various places?

Answer (score 0):

This is the descriptive error message:

> the following 1 voting nodes responded: 192.168.0.59:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 13.212.31.212:27017 failed with Received heartbeat from member with the same member ID as ourself: 0"

That is telling you that `192.168.0.59:27017` and `13.212.31.212:27017` are the same node, and you can't add the same node twice.